# samba permisions when copying files to file share

Tags: permissions, server-message-block

Maintainign a ubuntu server for a client where they use several file shares through smb.

Fileshares have permisions to user groups and are set to `0770`

Lately I get a lot of complaints from users who can't access files and it's always the same, for some reason the permissions of certain files /folders have changed ...

Already using create mask, but maybe I should put `"map archive = no"` in the default? Never used this in smb config so not sure what it does?

This is my share config in smb.conf

```
[file-share-name]
        writeable = yes
        path = /home/file-share
        write list = user1,user2,user3,@usergroup
        force directory mode = 770
        force group = usergroup
        force create mode = 770
        comment = usergroup
        valid users = user1,user2,user3,@usergroup
        user = user1,user2,user3,@usergroup
        create mode = 770
        browsable = yes
        directory mode = 770
```

Would adding a `"map archive = no"` avoid having to reset file permissions the whole time?

Comment: Are you sure your server hasn't been compromised?

Comment: Permisions are set to only read, not 777. Checked logs, host files, /var/www/hosts nothing there what is out of place. Also this is mainly used as file server not as a webserver.

Am asuming file permisions are getting skewed by users copying local files to the server and somehow permissions get copied aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you should need for samba is this

```
[sharename]
        create mask = 660
        directory mask = 770
        inherit acls = Yes
        path = /wherever/yourfolder
        read only = No
```

When a given user from a windows client does `create new folder` it should have permissions `drwxrwx---` and when doing `create new text file` that new file should be `-rw-rw----`.  If that does not happen, then to troubleshoot set the masks to 666 and 777 respectively or remove those two lines and see what happens after creating a new folder and new text file.

Obviously if you use masks 660 and 770 then be sure a given user has the correct group permissions.  By default all user accounts are typically in the `users` group, and that is their primary group, anything created by them will have the group permissions of `users` and it all should work seamlessly.